# Is it Possible to download PDF and than redirect to the given link

Tags: php, mpdf

I've been trying to Download PDF and soon after that redirect to the link. But haven't got any success yet.

If any one knows that would be a great help.

Here's what I've done till now.

```
 $this->layout = 'pdf';
         $mpdf = new mPDF('', 'A4');
         $mpdf->WriteHTML($chalan_html);
         $mpdf->Output('Student-challan.pdf', 'D');

         /*returning to the detail view of stuednt.*/
         header("Location:" . Url));
```

Thanks in advance.
Ali.

Comment: What have you done until now.

Comment: i've added the code into my question.

Comment: You cannot send header after outputting the data. You only option would be to redirect the user from the browser side.

Comment: You can save the file an then try to redirect the page. But if you kill output, you cannot do anything else.

Comment: I found out an alternate solution to this, I first save the data and pass extra id parameter in the URL link and  after redirection I've added hidden link in side that redirected page which trigger on document.ready and generate the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should add a download link in the student detail view.

This way you can see the detailed view of the student and download the file at the same time.